# How to get values on the third object of a Json with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am doing a get request on JS and with the json reponse i want to get some values, for example product and color, but i don't know how i can go more deeper on the next levels of the objects of the Json.

the Json:

```
{    
"items": {        
    "1man": {
        "312favorites": {
            "155description": {
                "color": "red",
                "price": 2.76666
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

}

I just can go until the 1man level i don't know how to get the next levels, my code until now

```
console.log(response.data.items['1man']);
```

If i try for example `console.log(response.data.items['1man'].312favorites` i get error on VScode, i want go to until the color value...

Does someone can help me here?

Comment: `response.data.items['1man']['312favorites']['155description'].color`

Comment: If the key begins with a number, you need to use square bracket notation like @GabrielePetrioli shows ↑

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
response.data.items['1man']['312favorites']['155description'].color
```

The reason is that the ***key*** has some numbers, and it can't be accessed with ***Dot notation*** because it has to be without any numbers or special characters that's why you must use ***Bracket notation*** .

Comment: Thank you a lot guys, before i had tried `response.data.items['1man'].['312favorites']`, but with the explanation i know now why it doesn't worked, thanks again.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome